# How to model a REST API with "POST to PUT redirect"?

Tags: http, rest, redirect, amazon-s3, api-design

I'm creating a REST API for a backup service, which in principle is quite simple:

- a user is identified by some `uid`;
- files are identified by some `fid`;
- to upload a file, the user `POST`s a file to `/backups/<uid>` and the location is returned
- to list files, the user `GET`s `/backups/<uid>` and some index of `fid`s is returned
- to download a file, the user picks one from the index, `GET`s `/backup/<uid>/<fid>` and the file is returned.

Now I'd like to greatly reduce traffic to my server by delegating up- and downloads to a service like Amazon S3.

Redirecting downloads is not a problem, since I could just perform a regular redirect (`301` or `307`?) to some generated expiring URL.

But what about the uploads? I hope to have something like this:

- a user (unaware of S3) starts to `POST` a file to my server
- the server receives the headers only (not the whole file!)
- the server determines a place in S3, generates an expiring URL for `PUT` and redirects to it
- the client `PUT`s the file to the URL it was handed by the server
- the server is notified of a successful upload

The point is that it all needs to be as transparent as possible to the users.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the initial POST should include the entire entity. Rather, the POST must explicitly be a request for an "upload bucket" resource to be created. You'd then simply respond to the POST request with `201 Created`, with the `Location` header pointing to the new resource where the file should be uploaded.

If the upload bucket chosen must depend on specifics of the file (file size, type), then I'd let the client submit metadata in the POST body.

Comment: Isn't it unRESTful that in this case the `Location` for `PUT` will not be valid anymore afterwards? Normally if you `PUT` something, you'd expect to be able to `GET` it after.

Comment: I think there's no such expectation. At any point in time (also right after the PUT) could another client issue DELETE on the particular resource. The "PUT, GET" sequence you describe does not happen within a transaction or so.

Comment: To be more precise, I think it could be said that there's an "expectation" that right after a PUT, a GET would return the entity that has been PUT there, yet there's no *requirement* for this to be the case. If the expectation of the client isn't met, this indicates that another client has been fussing with the resource.

Comment: Please note that it might take a while before I try this implementation. REST (pun intended) assured that I will get back to accept the answer if it turns out satisfactory.